# Excel VBA Object doesn't support this property

Tags: excel, vba, object, properties

I am fairly new to VBA. I have written a code to automate a workbook split into 30 new workbooks by specific criteria. It did work in the beginning, however now I am enhancing the code to add a new worksheet to the new workbook (which has a dynamic file name) and it breaks with different kinds of errors - Object doesn't support this property, or the file cannot be saved with this file extension (which worked before). Any suggestions on what is wrong?

The errors appear on the following lines:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AK100").Select`

`Selection.Paste`

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="SoC_File_Split\XXXX_RP_SoC_APAC_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("XFD4") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("XFD2") & ".xlsx"` - which worked fine before...

```
Sub apac()
'
' apac Macro
'

'
    Dim a As Workbook
    Set a = ThisWorkbook
    Dim aa As Worksheet
    Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(8)
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BB1048576").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="APAC"
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Dim path As String
    path = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & FolderName
    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir path
    Dim myFolder$
    UserName = Environ("username")
    myFolder = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\OneDrive - XXXXX\Desktop\SoC_File_Split"
    Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Paste
    Dim b As Workbook
    Set b = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim bb As Worksheet
    Set bb = b.Sheets("Sheet1")
    bb.Columns("A:ZZ").AutoFit
    bb.Range("A2:BB1048576").ClearFormats
    bb.Name = "Data"
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Data"))
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AK100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    b.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
    Selection.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="XXXX"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="SoC_File_Split\XXXX_RP_SoC_APAC_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("XFD4") & "_" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("XFD2") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Range` object doesn't have a `Paste` method. You should use `PasteSpecial` instead.

Comment: @Rory - thanks, I have fixed that part, however the main problem in the copy-paste operation is the copying part - a "Select method of range class failed" message pops up. I believe this is due to not being able to indicate the new wb adequately, due to its dynamic name. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AK100").Select` - this is the part of the code. Any idea on how to switch effectively between the two, without confusing the VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep selecting ranges to use them. You can replace this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AK100").Select
Selection.Copy
b.ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

with just this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:AK100").Copy Destination:=b.ActiveSheet.Range("a1")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are adding a new sheet

```vb
Set ws = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Data"))
```

but then you rename the Activesheet instead of that one, I think you should do

```vb
ws.Name = "Summary"
```

or

```vb
ws.Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
```

[EDIT]
Just saw that the newly created sheet becomes the ActiveSheet. Forget it.